# Android Google Map showing multiple markers on current location

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello everyone I am using custom marker image in google map. My problem is that when i click on that marker or zoom in or zoom out this marker duplicates means, more markers appears on the same location on different points. why this happening? how to avoid it?
Thanks in advance.

### Code

```
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
   {
     TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

     // Getting latitude of the current location
     latitude = location.getLatitude();

     // Getting longitude of the current location
     longitude = location.getLongitude();

     // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting position for the marker
    markerOptions.position(latLng);

    // Setting custom icon for the marker
    //  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.compass_needle));

    // Setting title for the infowindow


    // Adding the marker to the map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    // markerOptions.rotation(260);
  }
```

Comment: Show code you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding markers but you are not clearing previous added loation marker so You have to clear previously added marker when Location is changed again.

Add this line above `googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);`

```
googleMap.clear();
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am having problem with this when I use google map clear or marker.remove() it removes all the markers as I am getting additional marker for other users as well that are also been removed and it only shows the current updated marker of the user signed in

Answer (score 2):

More correct is to remove a specific marker, and don't clear the whole map.
Because you can have others markers and polylines on map.

In your case you have only one marker showing user location.
You can get it when adding.

```
private Marker mLocationMarker;

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ...
    if(mLocationMarker != null) {
        mLocationMarker.remove();
    } 
    mLocationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```